# Maximum and minimum number of articulation points in a graph with $n$ nodes

Tags: graph-theory

What's the maximum and minimum number of articulation points in a graph with $n$ nodes?

I think the maximum is $n-2$ because the graph would be a straight line, and the nodes at the two ends can't be articulation points because they don't have children.

I think the minimum is $0$ because you can have a complete graph and if you remove any of the nodes the rest of the nodes are still connected.

However I can't prove that my answer is correct.

What's the correct answer and how do you prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done, your results are fine
(except that you need to make a trivial exception for $n=1$).
You have already shown that the maximum is at least $n-2$.

To prove that the maximum is at most $n-2$, we show that every graph has at least two vertices that are NOT articulation points.

This follows from three observations:

1) An isolated vertex is never an articulation point.

2) A connected graph with at least two vertices has at least 2 vertices that are not articulation points

3) The number of non-articulation points in a disconnected graph equals the sum of the number of non-articulation points in its components.

Only the second item requires some justification, the others are obvious.

For the second item we recall the facts that every connected graph has a spanning tree, that a leaf in a tree is never an articulation point (for the tree),
and that a tree with at least two vertices has at least two leaves.
So a spanning tree has at least two vertices that are not articulation points(for the tree, so certainly not for the entire graph).

Comment: Why can't a node on a cycle be an articulation point ?
Consider the graph in the link -> https://postimg.org/image/l6q7y96cz/

The middle vertex is surely an articulation point.

Comment: @Lucifer Zedd: you are absolutely right, the argument was incorrect. The answer has been edited to remove the problem.